# html page in flex web application

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

how to display the html page in flexpopup  without using  iframe any idea?

Thanks,
aravindakumarThangaraju

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't because The Flash player does not render HTML.

Comment: hi,I dont this using iframe,the problem is in IE8 is working fine but other browser does't support any idea?

Comment: Drumbeat Insight has a Flex HTML Component.  It, basically, uses the iFrame trick but I think they've done a lot of work to address the oddities with the approach.